# GmailApp.sendEmail CC, CC not receiving

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send an CC email from a google form. The main person can receive the email notice but not the people on CC. Where is my mistake?

```
function submitForm(e){
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var message = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var question = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var answer = itemResponse.getResponse();
    message += (i + 1).toString() + '. ' + question + ': ' + answer + '\n';
}
  var address = "example@email.com"; // it is working untill here and can send email
  var cc = address+["example2@email.co.jp","example3@email.com.jp"]; // this is not working
  var title = '届出書が送信されました';
  var content = '以下の内容で届出書が送信されました。\n\n' + message;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(address, title, content);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value for `cc` should be a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC, you need to extra [options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) (see Advanced Parameters), like:

```
...
var address = "example@email.com";
var ccEmail = address + "," + "example2@email.co.jp","example3@email.com.jp";
var title = '届出書が送信されました';
var content = '以下の内容で届出書が送信されました。\n\n' + message;
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, title, content,{cc: ccEmail});
---
```

Comment: But now I am getting a error when I try to run it. :(

Comment: var address = "example@email.com"; 
var ccEmail = address + ",example2@email.com,example3@hotmail.co.jp,example4@email.com";
var title = '届出書が送信されました';
var content = '以下の内容で届出書が送信されました。\n\n' + message;
GmailApp.sendEmail(address, title, content,{cc: ccEmail});
  }